# How to get all attributes and methods in python object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I encountered such method called `__subclasscheck__`, however I could not find it with `dir(object)` or `inspect.getmembers(object)`, as it shows below.

```
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 13:42:34)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> import inspect
>>> [m for m in inspect.getmembers(object) if m[0].find("subclass") >= 0]
[('__init_subclass__', <built-in method __init_subclass__ of type object at 0x10d9903d8>), ('__subclasshook__', <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x10d9903d8>)]
>>> object.__subclasscheck__
<built-in method __subclasscheck__ of type object at 0x10d9903d8>
```

so I wonder whether there exists a way to list literally all attributes and methods in python object.

Comment: If it helps, [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) say: *"Note that these methods are looked up on the type (metaclass) of a class"*. Therefore, `'__subclasscheck__' in dir(type)`

Comment: @wjandrea or more directly, `vars(type)`

Comment: @juanpa You mean `'__subclasscheck__' in vars(type)`? I actually wrote that first but edited it out. What's the difference?

Comment: I feel it will be hard (and not well-defined) to list all of them considering `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` exist.

Comment: @wjandrea `vars(obj)` gives you the namespace of an object, it's basically the equivalent of `obj.__dict__`.

Comment: @JerieWang yeah, and other magical things as well. For sure it isn't well defined, that's why I tend to speak of names in namespaces to get a hold of something more concrete (although, even there you have the issue of slotted types)

Comment: Thank you, but this is still beyond my understanding, since `isinstance(object, type)` would return `True`, so `dir` an instance should basically show all methods defined, shouldn't it? maybe there exists magic I am not aware of between `object` and `type`